# can somebody help me with regexp_extract in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

can somebody help me with regexp_extract for this word "SUK-8935 Phase 58: Accessories Launch - Optase Cleaning Gel - UK"

i need the value "SUK-8935"

Comment: Please update your question with what all approaches you've tried and then the specific issue that you're facing. I think that way you'll get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```py
import re

your_string = "SUK-8935 Phase 58: Accessories Launch - Optase Cleaning Gel - UK"
output_match = re.search(r'SUK-[0-9]{4}', your_string)  # This is a Regex Match
result = output_match.group(0)
print("'output_string' type: ", type(result))
print("'output_string' result: ", result)
```

Which generates the following output (`result` is what you're looking for):

`'output_string' type:  <class 'str'>`

`'output_string' result:  SUK-8935`

Hope it helps.